# Is it correct to call multiple functions using a dictionary?

Tags: python

In an attempt to reduce excess conditions to call functions, I thought of calling them through a dictionary

Code with excess conditions

```py
command = input()

def do1():
    print('do nothing')

def do2():
    print('do nothing')

def do3():
    print('do nothing')

if command == '1':
    do1()

elif command == '2':
    do2()

elif command == '3':
    do3()

else:
    pass
```

Now in dictionary form

```py
command = input()

def do1():
    print('do nothing')

def do2():
    print('do nothing')

def do3():
    print('do nothing')

functions = {
    '1':do1,
    '2':do2,
    '3':do3
}

functions[command]()
```

This reduces the number of lines and makes the code cleaner, but is this the correct way?

Comment: Yes, this is called a dispatch table.

Comment: If it's always the same function, why use `if` or a dictionary in the first place? But yes, this is a valid method.

Comment: You are correct ;) just don't put the same method everywhere :p

Comment: yes, there is nothing wrong with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to being cleaner, this is not uncommon, and is fast (faster than the sequence of `if`'s because only one test is required), for the same reason network switches are fast.

This is also the closest you can get to using a `case` or `switch` statement in python. If you plan on writing a lot of code that uses the function table, you will probably want to also write a thin interface layer on top; it will allow you to later tweak the implementation, and you get to use things like default arguments. For instance, if you write the following code:

```
def do():
    print('do nothing')

functions = dict('1'=do, '2'=do, '3'=do)

def execute(*args, command=0):
    return functions[command](*args)
```

then you could later replace `execute` with a different function table that looks things up with a more specialized data structure, like:

```
# def do():
#    print('do nothing')
# functions = dict('1'=do, '2'=do, '3'=do)

_crazy_datastructure = ParallelizedFibonacciaHeapTreeGraphThing()

def execute(*args, command='1'):
    return _crazy_datastructure.perform_command(command, preprocess(*args))
```

If the number of functions in the table is very large or has some interesting substructure, an alternate implementation may be more efficient. Moreover, because you call the function with `execute(command='1')` it is more legible also.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason you can't just use an if statement here. Although your code will run `do()` no matter what as your `else` statement also runs do.

My assumption though is you want to run `do()` only if command is `1-5` otherwise do something else. In this case you could just employ a simple if statement:

```
command = input()

def do():
    print('do nothing')

if command in set('1234'):
    do()
else:
    do_something_else()
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is ok. This is a type of `caller dispatch` which you can connect command option to functions and translate command code into executable code.

[some example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182093/why-store-a-function-inside-a-python-dictionary/182095)

[reference to other caller dispatch methods](https://medium.com/better-programming/dispatch-tables-in-python-d37bcc443b0b)